# Main not returning 0

Tags: c++

So I have this exercise, I need to ask the user for 2 inputs (grades >0 <10) and then I have to print the average and then ask the user if they want to insert more grades 1-yes 2-no; if it's 1 then the program runs again, if it's 2 the program quits. But I'm having trouble to make the program quit.

```
// ConsoleApplication7.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    float n1;
    float n2;
    cin >> n1;
    cin >> n2;
    if ((n1 || n2) > 10) {
        cout << "Wrong grade";
    }
    else if ((n1 || n2) < 0) {
        cout << "Wrong grade";
    }
    else {
        cout << "The grade average is " << (n1 + n2) / 2 << endl;
        cout << "Do you want to insert more grades ? " << endl;
        int g;
        cin >> g;
        if (g = 1) {
            main();
        }
        else if (g = 2) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a `while` loop instead of calling `main()` again.

Comment: typos. `g  = 1` and `g = 2`. They need to be `g == 1` and `g == 2`.

Comment: It is undefined to call `main` in C++. Your program is invalid. Use a loop.

Comment: Calling main() within your program is a bad practise

Comment: Yeah, look up recursion and when it's appropriate to use it, and how you get out of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is to test for equality you need two `=`, not one so your two checks are actually assigning values to `g` not comparing with `g`

```
    if (g == 1) {
        main();
    }
    else if (g == 2) {
        return 0;
    }
```

Any modern compiler should have given you a compiler warning about that assignment. You should always try to pay attention to compiler warnings.

Also your logic of

```
if ((n1 || n2) > 10)
```

and

```
else if ((n1 || n2) < 0)
```

is incorrect, but I will leave it to you to figure out what is wrong (this is homework afterall).

Lastly you may want to look in to doing a `do-while` loop instead of calling `main()` over and over.

Comment: Upvoted for putting the constant first.

Comment: Downvoted for the same reason - that makes more harm than helps

Comment: @Slava really? Please give me a example of where it causes harm, because I can't think of any.

Comment: On one of my past jobs they had a class for a fixed point (to count money). It had `operator double()`. `if( 1.0 == money )` will give you endless headaches at debugging. Assignment instead of comparison problem is easily detected by any modern compiler.

Comment: I personally find the "constant first" idiom to be unreadable. I would much prefer declaring `g` as `const`, which does require putting the `int g; cin >> g;` in a separate function/lambda. But that's mostly a weak point of the standard streams, not `const`

Comment: I learned C++ back before compilers would give you a warning about assigning in a `if`, I guess I never really broke the habit.

Comment: @Slava I concede your point and removed that section of the answer and replaced it with a message about not ignoring compiler warnings.

Comment: Calling `main()` is illegal according to the standard. If compilers allow it it's a non-standard extension.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer!!! Simple and direct! And I figured out the 'or' part I fixed it with 'if ((n1 > 10) || (n2 > 10))
 {
  cout << "Wrong grade";
 }'

Answer (score 1):

Your `if`condition is wrong:

```
if (g = 1)
```

sets `g` to 1, and is always true. What you want to do is:

```
if (g == 1)
```

And as Scott said in his comment, you shouldn't call main but rather use a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at these modifications.

```
float n1;
float n2;
int g = 1;
while (g != 2)
{
    cout << "Please enter two grades: " << endl;
    cin >> n1;
    cin >> n2;
    if ((n1 || n2) > 10) {
        cout << "Wrong grade";
    }
    else if ((n1 || n2) < 0) {
        cout << "Wrong grade";
    }
    else {
        cout << "The grade average is " << (n1 + n2) / 2 << endl;
        cout << "Do you want to insert more grades ? " << endl;
        cin >> g;
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Also note that I moved using namespace outside of main.